# Quickest way to create UVs for a tileset using a single tiling texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I am still fairly new to Blender (couple months in)

Right now I'm working with a tileset that looks like this:

[image]

The code in Unity places these tiles procedurally and creates a world out of them. It works pretty well, but we would also ideally want to use a single texture on all of them.

The texture we have looks like this (the green tickmarks are guides for me and don't show up in the final model):

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the tile pieces that I have completed the UVs for. They work, and they tile correctly.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that this process takes a long time. I am basically moving UV vertexes around manually in the UV editor. Is there a better way to do this? As an aside, the seams I've chosen also look like crap in Unity, which is another issue but may be related to how I'm doing this.

We're trying to accomplish a look of "grass transitioning to dirt" in one texture and tileset, with a kind of cartoony, cell-shaded look.

[image]

Comment: What method did you use to unwrap your mesh?

Comment: I used the basic "UV Unwrap > Unwrap" method: http://i.imgur.com/Evbl8tC.png

Comment: you can use transfer UVmap to copy the uvmap from ine to others

Comment: @Chebhou That won't really work, though - for that, all objects "need" to have the same topology.

Comment: @Chebhou/@someonewithpc I just tried that and it threw this error: http://imgur.com/q63HgTY  I AM using a script that allows me to copy/paste my UVs, which helps a bit to speed things up, but I am hoping there is some fundamental process I'm not aware of

Comment: @user2092690 Yeah, that's what I said... Have you tried using the other unwrap methods? Try _Smart UV Project_ - it should give better results.

Comment: i suggest that you divide the texture and create 3 materials each one for a part of the texture than assign the materials to each part

Comment: I have tried others - they all kind of end up with the same problem though, which is that I end up poking and prodding the vertexes into place to get the tiling right.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [Data Transfer](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Modeling#Mesh_Data_Transfer) modifier, which will be released with the coming 2.74, but you can still experience it in the latest daily builds [here](http://builder.blender.org/download/).

- Add a **Data Transfer** modifier, choose the source object you want to copy from.
- Toggle *Face Corner Data* > *UVs*, then press **Generate Data Layers** button, which will generate a UV data for the new object (you cannot see it until the modifier is applied).
- Choose a proper method from the list on the right, you can preview it in GLSL shading mode. Finally, apply the modifier to generate a solid UV layer.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

**NOTE**:

1. For batch copying modifier among objects, you can enable the **Copy Attributes Menu** addon.
2. Since it is not fairly stable (currently), use it with caution.

Comment: "'Ctrl+L '-> Modifiers" works fine for copying modifiers without having to use an Addon.  The last selected object is the one from which the modifiers will be copied.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Right! thanks for reminding! But if the objects already got other different modifiers, it will not work for such case. I mean Ctrl L will overwrite the stack.

Comment: Interesting, by this I assume that you are saying that the Copy Attributes Addon will append Modifiers to the ones already there instead of replacing them?  That would make it very useful.

Comment: Yes, there is a separate operator for appending.